# Querying awkwardly stored data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Apologies for the vague title, but this is more a call for advice than a hunt for a direct answer.  For reference, I'm using SSMS 2014.

I'm working with a database that I did not create and I'm struggling to work with the data in its current format.  I have included an example of the table below.

```
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|DtID | ID | Mo1 | Mo2 | Tu1 | Tu2 | We1 | We2 | Th1 | Th2 | Fr1 | Fr2 |
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 565 | 12 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |
| 565 | 13 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| 565 | 14 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |
| 565 | 15 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   1 |
| 572 | 12 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| 572 | 13 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |
| 572 | 14 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| 572 | 15 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

DtID is a week commencing date identifier, ID is a person identifier, Mo1 represents Monday AM, Mo2 Monday PM, etc.  1 means person attended that session. The table exceeds 600k rows.

My problem occurs when trying to query data between specific date ranges, say for example I wanted to find a sum of present attendance marks between date idents 566 and 575.  Date 566 would refer to the Tuesday of week commencing 565, and 575 would refer to the Thursday of week commencing 572.

I would be much more comfortable with the table formatted in the form below (taking row 1 for example).

```
+-----+----+------+---------+
|DtID | ID | AMPM | Present |
+-----+----+------+---------+
| 565 | 12 |    1 |       0 |
| 565 | 12 |    2 |       1 |
| 566 | 12 |    1 |       0 |
| 566 | 12 |    2 |       1 |
| 567 | 12 |    1 |       1 |
| 567 | 12 |    2 |       0 |
| 568 | 12 |    1 |       0 |
| 568 | 12 |    2 |       0 |
| 569 | 12 |    1 |       1 |
| 569 | 12 |    2 |       0 |
+-----+----+------+---------+
```

Is this possible?  Is there an effective way to query the data as it is?  I'm fairly new to SQL and almost all of my learning so far has been from interpreting questions and answers on this site.  As I say, I don't really know the answer to what I'm looking for, so the collective advice and wisdom of users on here would be very useful to me.

Many thanks.

Comment: You're right. The second representation makes much more sense than the first. I would argue that the existing table design is flawed, but hey we have to work with what we've got. There are a number of ways to get it in the required form. You could cross join to another table to turn 1 row into 10 (which is what you want) - here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866952/merge-start-and-end-columns-to-one-column/40867201#40867201. You could use ten`union all` but generally they are difficult for the query planner to optimise.

Comment: Although it's a lot of work, if the database design is consistently this 'awkward', and you have to do a lot of reporting, you could build a data warehouse

Comment: I'd consider the second design flawed, too, because it makes really no representation of the weekday. And as there's no other criteria to sort by, it is impossible to tell which day a row in the second table refers to.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Nick.  I've made a mental note of this and will certainly use for reference with similar situations in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you would want to loose the day information

```
select  DtID,ID,left(day,2) as day,right(day,1) as AMPM,Present 

from    t unpivot (Present for day in (Mo1,Mo2,Tu1,Tu2,We1,We2,Th1,Th2,Fr1,Fr2)) t
```

---

```
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| DtID | ID | day | AMPM | Present |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | Mo  | 1    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | Mo  | 2    | 1       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | Tu  | 1    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | Tu  | 2    | 1       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | We  | 1    | 1       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | We  | 2    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | Th  | 1    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | Th  | 2    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | Fr  | 1    | 1       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 12 | Fr  | 2    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | Mo  | 1    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | Mo  | 2    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | Tu  | 1    | 1       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | Tu  | 2    | 1       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | We  | 1    | 1       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | We  | 2    | 1       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | Th  | 1    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | Th  | 2    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | Fr  | 1    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
| 565  | 13 | Fr  | 2    | 0       |
+------+----+-----+------+---------+
```

Comment: This is just about there for my purposes and I can use this to find my solution. If you note my 'preferred' alternative, day information is not lost as such, because the date ident increments based on the day.  For example Tuesday is represented by 566.

Comment: I didn't get the 'preferred' part

Comment: By preferred I was referring to the table in the original post that I'd feel more comfortable using.  The actual column headings for my data set are called 'RegIdentAM1' 'RegIdentAM2' etc. which I've called 'MoAM', 'TuAM', etc. in the example.  I have just used the right function to pull through a day ident and have added this to the date identifier and subtracted one which returns the correct date.  Very happy with your reply - I hadn't came across unpivot before, so I'm pleased to now have this at my disposal.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would push hard to restructure the data.  One way I have been able to do this in a production system is to use a renaming trick.  First create a new table and then create a view named the way the original table was named.  Existing reports and queries will still work until they are replaced based on performance requirements.

In the meantime you could use something more fancy like unpivot or join but I have always found a union solution to be simple to setup, maintain and never had performance issues.  You may have different results but its easy to test.

EDIT:
I ran a few tests on a dataset of 20,971,520 rows created by appending the data over and over again (Insert Temp Select * From Temp).

```
Select * From vTemp - 1:28

Select DtID,ID,col,Present
   From Temp UnPivot (Present For Col In (Mo1,Mo2,Tu1,Tu2,We1,We2,Th1,Th2,Fr1,Fr2)) T - 1:30    

Select * From vTemp Where ID = 12  - :23

Select DtID,ID,col,Present
   From Temp UnPivot (Present For Col In (Mo1,Mo2,Tu1,Tu2,We1,We2,Th1,Th2,Fr1,Fr2)) T 
Where ID = 12 :24
```

In summary, if you like the pivot it is much less typing.  For those who do not like the syntax of pivot you can use Union or Union All depending if you want to remove duplicates.

For example:

```
Drop Table Temp
Create Table Temp (DtID int, ID int, Mo1 bit, Mo2 bit, Tu1 bit, Tu2 bit, We1 bit, We2 bit, Th1 bit, Th2 bit, Fr1 bit, Fr2 bit)


Insert Temp Values ( 565 , 12 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 )
Insert Temp Values ( 565 , 13 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 )
Insert Temp Values ( 565 , 14 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 )
Insert Temp Values ( 565 , 15 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 )
Insert Temp Values ( 572 , 12 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 )
Insert Temp Values ( 572 , 13 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 )
Insert Temp Values ( 572 , 14 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 )
Insert Temp Values ( 572 , 15 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 )

Drop View vTemp
Go
Create View vTemp As
Select  DtID, ID, 'Monday' Day, 1 AmPm, Mo1 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Monday' Day, 2 AmPm, Mo1 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Tuesday' Day, 1 AmPm, Tu1 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Tuesday' Day, 2 AmPm, Tu2 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Wednesday' Day, 1 AmPm, We1 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Wednesday' Day, 2 AmPm, We2 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Thursday' Day, 1 AmPm, Th1 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Thursday' Day, 2 AmPm, Th2 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Friday' Day, 1 AmPm, Fr1 Present From Temp 
Union All
Select  DtID, ID, 'Friday' Day, 2 AmPm, Fr2 Present From Temp 

Go

Select * From vTemp Order By ID, DtID, Day, AmPm
```

Comment: He was talking about queries not DML.  I dont know of a way to represent the data the way he wants and be able to do inserts without changing the base design which I strongly recommend.

Comment: Was that a performance test? (1) how many times did you repeat it? (2) have you cleaned/filled the cache before each run? (3) did you take server time or client time? and how about changing `select *` to `select count(*)`?